# MySQL join query need array of values for one column

Tags: mysql

I don't know whether it is possible in MySQL or not. If someone has tried it, will reduce my time and number of lines in the code.

I have rating table, which has the following field

[image]

I have reason table, which has the following fields,

[image]

Also i have mapping table called rating_reason_mapping for mapping rating table and reason table

[image]

And i have the below query to fetch the details of these tables

```
SELECT ratings.id AS rating_id, ratings.user_id, ratings.mdn, ratings.rating_value, ratings.rated_time, ratings.comment, reasons.reason
FROM ratings, reasons
JOIN rating_reason_mapping
WHERE rating_reason_mapping.rating_id = ratings.id
AND reasons.id = rating_reason_mapping.reason_id
```

Of course it will display the result like below,

[image]

But this is not the result i am expecting one , i don't want the repetation of all the rows instead i need the reasons in an array.For example you can see that `rating_id` `59` has repeated three times. All the values except the reasons are same for these three. I don't need this to be repeat in three times. I just need this in one time only. But i need all the reasons of the three rows. The reasons should be in an array.Like below

[image]

Of course the rating id 71,46,47 and 20 will have values in the above result

Is this possible in MySQL ???

Comment: Try by changing `SELECT ratings.id AS rating_id,...` to `SELECT DISTINCT ratings.id AS rating_id,...`

Comment: Both of your answers did not solve my problem.  @Ollie Jones : When i run like you have marked as duplicate (SELECT ratings.id AS rating_id, ratings.user_id, ratings.mdn, ratings.rating_value, ratings.rated_time, ratings.comment, GROUP_CONCAT( reasons.reason
SEPARATOR ', ' )
FROM ratings, reasons
JOIN rating_reason_mapping
WHERE rating_reason_mapping.rating_id = ratings.id
AND reasons.id = rating_reason_mapping.reason_id)   I am getting the result only for rating Id 59. But what about the others rating id 71,46,47 and 20 ??

Comment: Try this query `SELECT ratings.id AS rating_id, ratings.user_id, ratings.mdn, ratings.rating_value, ratings.rated_time, ratings.comment, GROUP_CONCAT(reasons.reason)
FROM ratings, reasons
JOIN rating_reason_mapping
WHERE rating_reason_mapping.rating_id = ratings.id
AND reasons.id = rating_reason_mapping.reason_id GROUP BY  ratings.user_id`

Comment: Wow great its worked. Some minor change GROUP BY rating_id  worked. Thank you sathvik, thank you very much. You saved my lot of time

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen the table much carefully.